# How to use Micrometer timer together with webflux endpoints

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, micrometer

IS there any simple way to use Micrometer timers with Webflux controllers?

It seems that @Timed works only with non-reactive methods. For reactive it records very low time values.

I found a similar question: [How to use Micrometer Timer to record duration of async method (returns Mono or Flux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311495/how-to-use-micrometer-timer-to-record-duration-of-async-method-returns-mono-or) but the answers were too complex for such a common issue

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a `metrics()` method in both Mono and Flux that collects and publishes metrics about "the duration elapsed between a subscription and the onComplete termination of the sequence" to Micrometer. Did you try it?

Comment: Do you have reactive http endpoints? If you have then it is trivial to measure.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to measure time for Web-flux methods/calls you can then use easily metrics directly from Flux/Mono (plus configure your project to export metrics, e.g. for graphite)

An example looks like

```
Flux<String> dataStream = Flux.just("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD");
dataStream.name("my-test-name").tag("key1", "value1").metrics().subscribe(p ->
   {
      System.out.println("Hello " + p);
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
});
```

Then in my case the metrics in the graphite are e.g.under application-name.magdalena.**reactor.flow.duration.exception.flow.my-test-name.status.completed.type.Flux.p50** 
p50 - is the latency for the half of the requests (or p98 latency for 98% pf the requestsetc.). Thanks they the artificial delay in this example you can observe that they values is near 4000 (1s x 4 elements processed).

Configuration in application.yml for graphite:

```
management:
    metrics:
        export:
            graphite:
                enabled: true
                host: graphite-lhr10.something.com
                port: 2003
                protocol: plaintext
```

@Timed annotation did not worked fro me too.

Comment: How did you able to add percentiles like P50, P98? I can't find any solution. Can you help?